# Usage Patterns for JHipster once development has started

Tags: jhipster

this is what I have so far achieved with Jhipster:

1 - Create my entities and relationships
2 - Generated my application
3 - Built the application and confirmed that I am happy with the existing entity-relationships.

I am now ready to start writing business logic.

My concern is that I haven't found any information on the JHipster website to guide me.  I was hoping to find some guidance with regard to customisation and extension of the generated code.

I am wondering if there are any best practices ?

My next tasks are :

- customize the GUI - removing some elements that the user will not need to input but will be stored in the database.
- write java code to populate above elements in controllers
- write business logic that can be called by controllers

I am wondering what will happen when i need to alter the existing set of entities?

I am wondering what will happen when i need to add new entities?

I will need to regenerate the code.

So far from what I have read there is a lot of manual work involved to resolve the above once customisation/development has started.

Is this true ?

Does anyone have any suggestions on how best to proceed and use Jhipster in the most production manner - with as little manual "merging" as possible ?

Thanks a million,
Fergal.

Comment: You will use `yo jhipster:upgrade` to benefit from fixes from Jhipster team whiel keeping your custom code, see https://jhipster.github.io/upgrading-an-application/ To modify entities, you will edit their definitions in `.jhipster` folder, see https://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-entity/#updating-an-existing-entity Just give it a try and commit often.

Comment: Thanks.  I have committed to jhipster for now. Let's see how it goes.
I found this : https://www.slideshare.net/julien.dubois/devoxx-being-productive-with-jhipster
I may reply to my own question when I have more experience with the tool.